# Unknown column in where clause of subquery-of-subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I am calculating the average of 5 last process execution, for that I am using a subquery since limit clause will calculate the average of all executions and not only 5. My problem is that in my subquery I have an unknown column error on the where clause. 
Should I use join instead of subqueries? How can I achieve that?

```
SELECT s.id, s.name,ssch.name,s.refresh_delay,
(SELECT MAX(start_time) FROM runs    WHERE sp_id = s.id) AS    last_run_started,
(SELECT MAX(start_time) FROM runs WHERE sp_id = s.id AND sp_run_status_id = 27  AND confidence_level >= 90 AND manual_approval_id IN (0,1)) AS last_run_accepted,
(SELECT last_run_started + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) AS dwt,
(SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(times.completion_time) - TIME_TO_SEC(times.start_time))) AS tw FROM 
(SELECT completion_time, start_time FROM runs **WHERE  sp_id = s.id** LIMIT 5) times) tw
  FROM spouses s 
LEFT JOIN `time_zones` tz ON tz.`id` = `time_zone_id`
```

Comment: You got `Unknown column error` because your subquery contain column that isn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query, simplified to show only the important part for the question:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, ssch.name, s.refresh_delay,
       (SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(times.completion_time) -TIME_TO_SEC(times.start_time))) AS tw
        FROM (SELECT completion_time, start_time
              FROM runs
              **WHERE  sp_id = s.id**
              LIMIT 5
             ) times
       ) tw
FROM spouses s LEFT JOIN
     `time_zones` tz 
     ON tz.`id` = `time_zone_id`;
```

Two issues with this logic:

1. (The most important) MySQL does not support correlation clauses in nested sub-sub queries.  That is, the correlation clause can refer to the outer query, but not to an outer-outer query.
2. Second, using `limit` without `order by` is suspect.

One way is to do the aggregation as a subquery in the `FROM` clause, using variables to enumerate the rows for each `sp_id`:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, ssch.name, s.refresh_delay,
       t.tw
FROM spouses s LEFT JOIN
     `time_zones` tz 
     ON tz.`id` = `time_zone_id` LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT sp_id, SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(times.completion_time) -TIME_TO_SEC(times.start_time))) AS tw
      FROM (SELECT sp_id, completion_time, start_time,
                   (@rn := if(@spid = sp_id, @rn + 1,
                              if(@spid := sp_id, 1, 1)
                             )
                   ) as seqnum
            FROM runs r CROSS JOIN
                 (SELECT @spid := 0, @rn := 0) params
            ORDER BY sp_id, start_time desc
           ) times
      WHERE seqnum <= 5    
      GROUP BY sp_id
     ) t
     ON t.sp_id = s.id
```

Comment: I changed your `ORDER BY sp_id` to `ORDER BY start_time desc` to get last 5 started runs and I tested it. I am not getting the same result when running the subquery alone, it means that when I test the subquery only this way `(SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(times.completion_time) -TIME_TO_SEC(times.start_time))) AS tw FROM (SELECT completion_time, start_time FROM runs WHERE sp_id = 130 order by start_time desc LIMIT 5 ) times ) tw` I am getting 00:43:23.8000 as result which is correct but when I'm executing your query I am getting 01:08:21.4545 as average of last 5 runs for the `sp_id` 130

Comment: Your query is calculating the average of all runs.

Comment: Your `WHERE seqnum <= 5 ` is ignored

Comment: The correct `order by` is `ORDER BY sp_id, start_time`.  `sp_id` has to be first.